# Generics in typescript object indexers

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've been trying to make a type whose indexer has a return type which is based upon a string literal for the key.

```
export enum Units {
    Enum = 'enum',
    String = 'string',
    Boolean = 'bool',
    Pounds = 'pounds'
}

export type AConditional<T extends Units> = T extends 'string' ? string : T extends 'bool' ? boolean : number;

type AType = {
    <T extends Units>[Key in `${string}/${T}`]: AConditional<T>;
}
```

I'm aiming for

```
const a: AType = {};
typeof a['whatever/pounds'] === 'number'
typeof a['something/bool'] === 'boolean'
typeof a['something/string'] === 'string'
a['something/notaunit'] //Error
a['wrong key'] //Error
```

The only part I have been unable to solve is how to add generics to an object indexer, obviously adding it before the brackets like I have in the snippet does not work, and putting it in the type's generics does not work either because then the object must have a generic which does not work for my case. Does anyone know any solutions to make it work as shown above?

Comment: You can't add generics to an object indexer. Why can't you do `AType<"whatever/pounds"> === "number"`?

Answer (score 2):

You were pretty close, but a relatively new feature of TypeScript is using `as` in mapped types to "rename" keys:

```
type AType = {
    [T in Units as `${string}/${T}`]: AConditional<T>;
};
```

And because `Units` is just an enumeration, we can use `T in Units` directly.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwKqIJYwM5wDeAsAFBwVwCiK6AvHAORJqMA0ZlcAyjFNogDmcBozx8Bg9p0oAhCBAA2wAIaIRTAEYLF08pQAKEZIgAmBUZBPnGZAL5kyoSLDgwAnmGBwAggGEIM1xsQJVFAB4AFQQQGCRzTBx8AD4NaNA4swIxCSFGOAB+OHF+ITgALjh02Pjs7SV8ovrlNQq4Wk1gKABuR1IPL19Iz28GEn0KAG1ogUTcAhUCAAMAEkISyTsAejXIuyWAXUr-QNNg0IjI5N7SOxuyU2AAY0UVKG8nwPE4FWPhr3u-RGEAAZj9JowAO4ACxUcQAbl0tlYsowDiI6KIOl1bECvKDwWIIKhgDBoZIts00RjRM1VIhcQNgASVBC8MTSeShFsNnl0ZjRLypGRWUSSWSKYgIDAVCZcNStlsqFAoNARRDIaqygBrYDuBVKlXQIA)